# Are there any absolute values I can use for unit testing geodesic calculations?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gis

I am writing unit tests that test if my geodesic calculations are correct.

Is there any absolute values I can input to test if my bearing and range calculations are correct.  In other words, is there a set of two coordinates that we *know* the distance between and the bearing from Point A to Point B?

I have not been able to find some kind of industry-standard values in my research.

Comment: Just use two fixed points, [45 S, 90 W] to [45 N, 90 E], Google says _15,882 km_.  _https://www.google.com/search?q=distance+from+45+S+90+W+to+45+N+90+E_

Comment: @Relias, doesn't that beg the question of how Google knows their calculation is correct?

Comment: They're a part of a conglomerate, so through the use of _satellites_ and _[lidar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidar)_.  There is a newer type of _lidar_ also; the name escapes me.  And, their GPS is super accurate.  I trust it, the precision is about 50 meters, at the most.

Comment: @Relias, very insightful!  I appreciate that.  I did, ultimately, use this technique as a means to approximate accuracy.